# How to test client-server interaction based on server output with pytest?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, pytest

I want to implement the following scenario:

1. [Thread 1] Run server via `subprocess` in separate Python thread #2.
2. [Thread 2] Take a lock until specific line appears in server output.
3. [Thread 1] Try to acquire lock and wait until it's released by thread #2.

Some relevant code:

```
self._proc = subprocess.Popen([self._bin] + self._args, shell=False, bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while self._proc.poll() is None:
    line = self._proc.stderr.readline()
    if 'Ready for connections' in line:
        break
self._lock.release()
```

But the problem is - it doesn't work inside pytest.
If I run my test with `-s` argument, then it works. Otherwise, it just hangs forever on acquisition of lock in another thread.

Also I tried to use fixtures `with capsys.disabled()` and `with capfd.disabled()` but without success.

Is there a simple way to disable capturing of subprocess outputs only? Or should it work out-of-the-box and maybe I just have some other flaw in the code?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you're describing; in fact, I'm using the approach of capturing output of the `subprocess.Popen` quite often (although usually via `for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''): if not line: break` snippet). Can you include a [mcve] for a chance?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [pytest-xprocess](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xprocess) could be used here. It provides a simple fixture `xprocess`  which can be used to start an instance of your server in a separate process and make it available in your tests. It will also create a process `logfile` that you can use to monitor the process output during testing.